# ListFragment pagination?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm tired to looking up for pagination in `ListFragment` ,Is there any way to do it?

Any suggestion would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library called "Endless Adapter" that was developed by CommonsWare. It could be what you are looking for. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless . The introduction reads "AJAX Web sites have sometimes taken up the "endless page" model, where scrolling automatically loads in new content, so you never have to click a "Next" link or anything like that.

Wouldn't it be cool to have that in an Android application? Kinda like how the Android Market does it?"